# How to make IMPORTXML function in GoogleSheets work with Russian Central Bank currency exchange rates?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am working on a financial model for the client and doing benchmarking with some competitors, including a company located in Russia. For that reason I need to retrieve historical data on the USD:RUB conversion rates.

I tried using IMPORTXML function for that in the form given below:

=IMPORTXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1="&TEXT($C$74,"dd.mm.yyyy")&"&date_req2="&TEXT($C$74+1,"dd.mm.yyyy")&"&VAL_NM_RQ=R01235","//Value")/10000

where $C$74 is the cell where I store the date of interest.

It worked for a bit returning the needed exchange rate robustly, but then suddenly last week the cell returned an "#N/A" Error with the following description: "Error
Could not fetch url: [http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=01.04.2023&date_req2=02.04.2023&VAL_NM_RQ=R01235"](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=01.04.2023&date_req2=02.04.2023&VAL_NM_RQ=R01235%22),

although I did not make any changes to the cell with the formulae.

What can be the problem? And if any, what could be the solution?

Intially I thought that I accidentally deleted something in the formulae, but I did not.

While trying to figure out what is going on, I accidentally deleted one symbol, that I thought might have caused the problem. Then I realized that I was wrong and pressed "Undo (Ctrl+Z)" button effectively returning to the initial formulae I had. Suddenly, the formulae worked as intended and I received the correct currency exchange rate, which I needed.

This effect lasted until I closed the spreadsheet and opened it up again. The error came back again.

Formulae seems to be correct and work okay, but for some reason it does not.

I would really appreciate your input and suggestions.

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Maxim